# Apply mapping to subset of fields in single JSLT transform

Tags: json, jslt

I have json input like this:

```
{
  "sys_id": "651bc076db1b00107e032a9a4896192f",
  "xxx_operation": "update",
  "xxx_table_name": "customerservice_case"
  "case": "upd12CS0001001",
  "short_description": "upd12"
}
```

There are 4 types of *tables*, defined in `xxx_table_name`

I would want to apply different mappings depending on the value of `xxx_table_name`.
Also, some fields (like `xxx_operation` and `sys_id`) are common to all types of jsons.

What would be the proper way to do this transform with JSLT?

Ideally there would be transformations for the common fields and then specific transformations for the rest of the fields. Pseudocode:

```
{
    "operation": .xxx_operation, 
    "id": .sys_id,
    if (.xxx_operation == 'customerservice_case') {
        // customerservice_case specific transformations here
    }
    else if (.xxx_operation == 'customerservice_ticket') {
        // customerservice_ticket specific transformations here
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge together JSON objects using the `+` operator, so the custom code you have *almost* works. If you do this:

```
{
    "operation": .xxx_operation, 
    "id": .sys_id
} +
if (.xxx_operation == 'customerservice_case') {
    // customerservice_case specific transformations here
}
else if (.xxx_operation == 'customerservice_ticket') {
    // customerservice_ticket specific transformations here
}
```

it will work. (I'm assuming the tests should really be on the value of `xxx_table_name`, but no matter.)